# PowerShell -replace to get string between two different characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am current using split to get what I need, but I am hoping I can use a better way in powershell.

Here is the string:

```
server=ss8.server.com;database=CSSDatabase;uid=WS_CSSDatabase;pwd=abc123-1cda23-123-A7A0-CC54;Max Pool Size=5000
```

I want to get the server and database with out the database= or the server=

here is the method I am currently using and this is what I am currently doing:

```
$databaseserver = (($details.value).split(';')[0]).split('=')[1]
$database = (($details.value).split(';')[1]).split('=')[1]
```

This outputs to:

```
ss8.server.com
CSSDatabase
```

I would like it to be as simple as possible.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replacing approach**

You may use the following regex replace:

```
$s = 'server=ss8.server.com;database=CSSDatabase;uid=WS_CSSDatabase;pwd=abc123-1cda23-123-A7A0-CC54;Max Pool Size=5000'
$dbserver = $s -replace '^server=([^;]+).*', '$1'
$db = $s -replace '^[^;]*;database=([^;]+).*', '$1'
```

[image]

The technique is to match and capture (with `(...)`) what we need and just match what we need to remove.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of the line
- `server=` - a literal substring
- `([^;]+)` - Group 1 (what `$1` refers to) matching 1+ chars other than `;`
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible

Pattern 2 is almost the same, the capturing group is shifted a bit to capture another detail, and some more literal values are added to match the right context.

**Note**: if the values you need to extract may appear anywhere in the string, replace `^` in the first one and `^[^;]*;` pattern in the second one with `.*?\b` (any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible followed with a word boundary).

**Matching approach**

With a `-match`, you may do it the following way:

```
$s -match '^server=(.+?);database=([^;]+)'
```

The `$Matches[1]` will contain the server details and `$Matches[2]` will hold the DB info:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              CSSDatabase
1                              ss8.server.com
0                              server=ss8.server.com;database=CSSDatabase
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `server=` - literal substring
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: any 1+ non-linebreak chars as few as possible
- `;database=` - literal substring
- `([^;]+)` - 1+ chars other than `;`

Comment: Wow, thank you for this! Just one thing, if I wanted to trap when say either "database=" or "server=" does not exist how can I alert the match statement or replace statement.

Comment: @Stealthmatt You may use `$a.Contains("server=")` approach. Or when using a matching approach, check if `$Matches` actually has any value.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with a RegEx and named capture groups, similar to Wiktor's Matching Approach.

```
$s = 'server=ss8.server.com;database=CSSDatabase;uid=WS_CSSDatabase;pwd=abc123-1cda23-123-A7A0-CC54;Max Pool Size=5000'
$RegEx = '^server=(?<databaseserver>[^;]+);database=(?<database>[^;]+)'
if ($s -match $RegEx){
    $Matches.databaseserver
    $Matches.database
}
```